# SQL Server - Using Case in a Where IN section of a Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use `CASE` for a `WHERE IN` clause of my code in a join. Is this not possible to do or is my syntax just bad? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
LEFT JOIN 
    MyTable ON MyTable.ID = SomeTable.ID 
            AND MyTable.ResultDate IN (CASE 
                                          WHEN metricid IN ('0040','0015') 
                                             THEN '('01312016','03312016','06302016')' 
                                             ELSE '('20160630')' 
                                       END)
```

I am using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (like `a+b`) that can return **exactly one atomic value** - a string, an int, a datetime - but it **cannot** return a string that needs to be interpreted as a list of value (for the `IN` operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't but you can do something like this:

```
LEFT JOIN 
    MyTable ON MyTable.ID = SomeTable.ID 
            AND ((metricid IN ('0040','0015') AND MyTable.ResultDate IN ('01312016','03312016','06302016')) OR ((metricid NOT IN ('0040','0015') AND MyTable.ResultDate='20160630')))
```

It's ugly but it should work :)

Anoter approach would be to have to queries and do a UNION. So, the first one filters by metricid IN ('0040','0015') and does a LEFT JOIN to MyTable based on ResultDate IN ('01312016','03312016','06302016'). And the other one filters by metricid NOT IN.

Comment: Agreed, doesn't look too nice but it works! Thanks. Maybe SQL 2032 will have something a little neater we can use